# JSFiddle code not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/G5Y8p/9/

I have copied this JSFiddle code from the link given above.But it is not working in my browser can anyone help me with this?
I am new in these things.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $win = $(window),
        w = 0,
        h = 0,
        rgb = [],
        getWidth = function () {
            w = $win.width();
            h = $win.height();
        };

    alert($win.width());
    $win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function (e) {

        rgb = [
        Math.round(e.pageX / w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY / h * 255),
        150];

        $('body').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + rgb.join(',') + ')');

    }).resize();

});
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery library in your page?  This example leverages jQuery ($)

Comment: you have to define what you mean by "not working". Have you looked in console for any errors (hit f12 and look for console tab)? What is the expected behavior vs what is going on? Since we can't see your browser these details are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add this as an answer because the comments section simply cannot handle the content im trying to get across.

JS Fiddle does not normally generate references when you run code in the editor.

Try adding the following to your HTML/PHP or whatever file type you are using for markup.

```
<head> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```

It sounds like you havent included the necessary references to both JQuery and JQuery UI.